# need mod_rewrite exceptions for urls starting with certain characters

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I don't know much about mod_rewrite, but can't seem to find an answer to this question.  I'm developing a simple app and routing all urls (with the exception of a few) through the main index.php page.  so for example mysite.com/test goes goes to index.php, then determines in php what the url is and loads the appropriate page.

My issue is that I need to exclude email verifications, or other potential future exceptions from this rule.  An example of an email verification link is: http://myrul.com/php-login-advanced/register.php?id=2&verification_code=..... etc.

So... is there a way to exclude a url from the rewrite rules that starts with certain characters. "php-" would do the trick in this case.

My current rewrite conditions are:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|&|register\.php|php|
css|images|javascript|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can exclude a particular URI using `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}` like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/php- [NC]
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|register\.php|php|css|images|javascript|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using query string

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}     ^query=(.*)$    [NC]
```

Comment: This string makes the activation link work, however breaks sending mysite.com/login, or anything else through the main index.php page.  After playing around with it a little more, I can just modify my existing code if there is a way to just allow php variables.